# Is it possible to specify styling of a component from outside?

Tags: angular

Is it possible to specify markup/styling to a component from outside? Eg, in the following component, how could I make the `{{name}}` italic or bold? I want to give the user the option to decide which style they prefer.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'rio-child',
  template: `
        Name is {{this.name}} <!-- user should specify whether name should be displayed in italic or bold -->
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() name:string;
}
```

Comment: How can you style text content with no tags enclosing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add input properties to your component, put the text in a `span` element, and style it with property binding:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'rio-child',
  template: `
    Name is <span [style.font-weight]="isBoldName" [style.font-style]="isItalicName">{{name}}</span>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() name:string;
  @Input() isBold: boolean;
  @Input() isItalic: boolean;

  public get isBoldName(): string {
    return this.isBold ? "bold" : "normal";
  }

  public get isItalicName(): string {
    return this.isItalic ? "italic" : "normal";
  }    
}
```

The property would be set in markup this way:

```
<rio-child [name]="My name" [isBold]="true" [isItalic]="false"></rio-child>
```

---

If you want a more versatile option, you can provide an input property to set the style attributes in one object and bind the `[ngStyle]` property of the span element to that property:

```
`Name is <span [ngStyle]="style">{{name}}</span>`
```

```
@Input() style: any;
```

```
<rio-child [name]="My name" [style]="{'font-weight': 'bold', 'color': 'green'}"></rio-child>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case your user can just use this css

```
rio-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

but in more complex case, if you want a user to be able to customize your component css ( without usage of [::ng-deep](https://hackernoon.com/the-new-angular-ng-deep-and-the-shadow-piercing-combinators-deep-and-drop-4b088dbe459) ) you have to specify that your component dont use css encapsulation

```
@Component({
    selector: 'rio-child',
    template: '<...>',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

( [see doc here](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) )